# Validating two fields with one submit button

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Apologies if this is completely obvious but I'm very new to Javascript & I'm not exactly a coding whizz. I'd like to validate two very simple forms using one submit button but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. Any pointers would be lovely! Here's my code so far

```
function checkName() {
    var x = document.forms["Name"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}

function checkEmail() {
    var x = document.forms["Mail"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

```
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="teststyle.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<form name="Name" action="MyForm.html" onsubmit="return checkName()"
method="post">
First name: <input name="fname" type="text"> <br>
<br>
Email: <input name="Mail" type="text">
</form>
<br>
<input value="Submit" type="submit"><br>
<br>
</body>
```

Comment: Where are two forms in your HTML code? Two forms or two fields on the same single form?

Comment: Oh dear, my code was all muddled up! Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validating two forms is not very useful, as you can only submit one at a time. You seem to be a bit confused between the concept of a form and a field. Everything you want to submit in a single go, should be a separate field in one form. For example, in a comment box, the "Name", "Email" and "Comment" fields would be `<input>`s in a single `<form>`. Your code should probably look like this:

```
function checkName() {
    var x = document.forms["Newsletter"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}

function checkEmail() {
    var x = document.forms["Newsletter"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
<body>
  <form name="Newsletter" action="MyForm.html" onsubmit="return checkName() && checkEmail()">
    First name: <input name="fname" type="text"> <br>
    <br>
    Email: <input name="email" type="text">
    <br>
    <input value="Submit" type="submit"><br>
  </form>
</body>
```

or you may want to combine them into a single function

```
<form name="Newsletter" action="MyForm.html" onsubmit="return formIsValid()" method="post">
```

where `formIsValid` looks something like

```
function formIsValid()
{
  return checkName() &&
         checkEmail();
}
```

or the more verbose

```
function formIsValid()
{
  if (!checkName())
    return false; // name invalid

  if (!checkEmail())
    return false; // mail invalid

  // All validations passed
  return true;
}
```

Also, please make sure to put your submit button *inside* the form, i.e. before the closing `</form>` tag.

Comment: Oh brilliant thank you so much! Apologies for my ignorance, I'm still a beginner!

Comment: No problem @user2984273, just study the code and compare it with your own to see the changes I've made. (I just edited to fix some bugs by the way, be careful that you are using the same form name and field names in your Javascript as you have given them with the `name` attribute in HTML).